# ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected while Installing UbuntuStudio on my MSI GP62 6QF Leopard PRo

Tags: boot, msi

I'm sorry to open a new thread with a question already opened.
The problem is that the commands suggested in others thread worked, but system seems not completely installed since when I simply turn on the PC the OS is not working, but when I go to the boot and turn on the OS in recovery mode it seems ok. 
Now, i'm totally new with Linux and computers in general, what should I do?
I'm now installing every update but I'm afraid this wont work.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

This kernel error message comes from the kernel ACPI Embedded Controller (EC) driver. The EC driver has tried to evaluate the ACPI _REG (operation region) control method and this has failed for some reason; most times this is a BIOS issue in the ACPI Machine Language that the _REG control was written in. However, the EC driver will work around this error and still get the EC handler installed and working, so generally one should not have any further issues with the EC controls.

Comment: Thanks a lot!| So, what should I do? contact support for BIOS update?

Comment: I personally wouldn't worry about it, the Linux kernel works around the issue, so it's not worth the risk of a BIOS update in my opinion.

Comment: I did not understand, so what you would recommend? i checked and I have the last EC firmware